# Validating Input::json() in Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, angular-resource

Validation does not work with Input::json. Ive tried different ways using json_decode/using arrays but still no luck. Here's my code:

```
//routes.php
Route::get('create', function() {

    $rules = array(
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    );

    $input = Input::json();
    //var_dump($input); //outputs std obj with correct inputs
    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);
    if ($validation->fails()) { //throws exeption "Call to a member function to_array() on a non-object"
        return Response::json($validation->errors->all());
    }

}
```

I'm posting the data using Angular Resource...but it always throws an error "Call to a member function to_array() on a non-object"...I cant paste my angular code since I can't format it correctly and stackoverflow doesn't allow me to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because in the input::json() returns an object and validation method expects either array or eloquent object. What you can do is convert the object to an array.

```
$input = Input::json();
$input_array = (array)$input;

$validation = Validator::make($input_array, $rules);
```

Updated:

After discussing with @Ryan, I noticed the problem is not from the validation, but in the the response::eloquent() was passed with an array instead of an eloquent object.

Comment: Ive already tried converting Input::json to array and everything but I still get the same error "Call to a member function to_array() on a non-object"; var_dumping returns $input return correct array. I'm scratching my head on this.

Comment: @Ryan Can u paste the full error message on paste.laravel.com and share the link here

Comment: Unhandled Exception
Message:

Call to a member function to_array() on a non-object

Location:
`
C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\framework\laravel\helpers.php on line 288
<br />
I dont know why laravel is calling to_array() of an array...im passing an array parameter already not an object.

Comment: can u get online on Laravel IRC

Comment: Ive tried posting it on IRC but nobody tried to reply me...Ive pasted my code here: [link](http://paste.laravel.com/fNI) and then posted it on IRC channel but still got no reply.

Comment: Are you calling any where that helper function eloquent_to_json(), can you paste the full controller or route method you have put this code. Paste it to http://paste.laravel.com

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23401/discussion-between-raf-and-ryan)

Comment: heres my controller code http://paste.laravel.com/fO2 ...i dont know..im still new to laravel so I cant dig in to the core to much.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, but for another problem.  Thanks, Raf.

Answer (score 0):

As of [at least] Laravel 5.3, you need to add the ->all() to the answer @Raftalks posted. Here's a shorthand method to automatically throw an exception (422), with all the errors, in one line:

```
use Validator;
use Input;

... other stuff

Validator::make((array)Input::json()->all(), ["rule"=>"filter"])->validate();
```